# MS SQL Server - Summarize on one line

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a Reps Commission Report - below is my SQL Statement.

```
SELECT
PostAR.TxDate
 ,PostAR.AccountLink
 ,PostST.AccountLink AS StkLnk
 ,PostST.Quantity AS QtySold
 ,PostST.cAuditNumber
 ,(PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost) AS Profit
 ,(((PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost)))/((((PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit))))*100 AS GrossProfitPercent
 ,(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost) AS Cost
 ,(PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit) AS TotSales
 ,(((PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost))) / ((((PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost)+(0.00000000000001))))*100 AS MarkUpPercent
 ,concat(StkItem.Code, ' - ' ,StkItem.Description_1) AS StkItemCode
 ,SalesRep.Code AS RepCode
 ,SalesRep.Name AS RepName
 ,Client.Account CustID
 ,Client.Name AS CustName,

CASE 
         WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) > 0 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 25  THEN 2
         WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 25 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 35  THEN 2.5
         WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 35 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 45  THEN 3
         WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 45 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 55  THEN 3.5
         WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 55 THEN 4
         ELSE 0
END AS CommPayablePercent

FROM PostAR 
 INNER JOIN PostST
ON PostST.cAuditNumber = PostAR.cAuditNumber
 INNER JOIN StkItem
ON StkItem.StockLink = PostST.AccountLink
 INNER JOIN SalesRep
ON SalesRep.idSalesRep = PostAR.RepID
 INNER JOIN Client
ON Client.DCLink = PostAR.AccountLink
```

What I want now - get ONE rep to post on the line - with their total sales. Otherwise the rep is split between each and every transaction they have made. This makes for a mission when it comes to summarising in Excel.

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with?  How does the query posted fit into your question?  What results are the query giving in comparison to the results you need?

Comment: You've got no aggregation or grouping in your query, so it's not going to summarize anything.

Comment: @Andrew Where would I place aggregation? Would I need to use a SUM() in the SELECT section and then do I GROUP BY that specific SUM() at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, using your exact query above and then an aggregating query.  The only aggregate you specified was TotSales - but hopefully the pattern becomes clear.

```
; -- WITH must be proceeded by a semicolon....weird but true (could be on prior stmt
WITH SalesDetail as (
    SELECT
    PostAR.TxDate
     ,PostAR.AccountLink
     ,PostST.AccountLink AS StkLnk
     ,PostST.Quantity AS QtySold
     ,PostST.cAuditNumber
     ,(PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost) AS Profit
     ,(((PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost)))/((((PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit))))*100 AS GrossProfitPercent
     ,(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost) AS Cost
     ,(PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit) AS TotSales
     ,(((PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost))) / ((((PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost)+(0.00000000000001))))*100 AS MarkUpPercent
     ,concat(StkItem.Code, ' - ' ,StkItem.Description_1) AS StkItemCode
     ,SalesRep.Code AS RepCode
     ,SalesRep.Name AS RepName
     ,Client.Account CustID
     ,Client.Name AS CustName,

    CASE 
             WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) > 0 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 25  THEN 2
             WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 25 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 35  THEN 2.5
             WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 35 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 45  THEN 3
             WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 45 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 55  THEN 3.5
             WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 55 THEN 4
             ELSE 0
    END AS CommPayablePercent

    FROM PostAR 
     INNER JOIN PostST
    ON PostST.cAuditNumber = PostAR.cAuditNumber
     INNER JOIN StkItem
    ON StkItem.StockLink = PostST.AccountLink
     INNER JOIN SalesRep
    ON SalesRep.idSalesRep = PostAR.RepID
     INNER JOIN Client
    ON Client.DCLink = PostAR.AccountLink 
  )
SELECT  SalesDetail.RepName
,   SalesDetail.RepCode
,   SUM(SalesDetail.TotSales) As RepTotSales

FROM SalesDetail
GROUP BY SalesDetail.RepName, SalesDetail.RepCode
```

Comment: Oh: I assumed RepCode was the ID of the RepName...but that was just an assumption ;-)